# R package: Can't render pdf manual using mathjaxr

Tags: r, latex, mathjax, r-package

I'm trying to use `mathjaxr` to include some LaTeX equations in the documentation of an R package. I'm using `\mjdeqn{latex}{ascii}` and `mjeqn{latex}{ascii}`, for example:

```
 \mjdeqn{\operatorname{P} \left( \operatorname{H_0} | x \right) = \left( 1 + \frac{1 - \pi_0}{\pi_0} \, \frac {1}{\operatorname{B}_{01} \left( x \right) } \right) ^{-1}}{P(H_0 | x) = (1 + ((1 - pi_0) / pi_0) * (1 / B_01(x)))^(-1)}
```

- The html documentation renders perfectly (with `?foo` and also in the `pkgdown` website of the package).
- `mathjaxr::preview_rd("foo", type = "html")` also renders ok.
- The ascii version renders on the shell without problems.

But when I try to render the pdf manuals I get errors:

```
mathjaxr::preview_rd("bfactor_to_prob", type = "pdf")

Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  unable to run pdflatex on 'Rd2.tex'
LaTeX errors:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \operatorname 
                         {P} \left ( \operatorname {H_0} | x \right ) = \lef...
l.36 ...}_{01} \left( x \right) } \right) ^{-1}}{}
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ratorname {P} \left ( \operatorname 
                                                  {H_0} | x \right ) = \left...
l.36 ...}_{01} \left( x \right) } \right) ^{-1}}{}
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \operatorname 
                         {B}_{01} \left ( x \right ) 
l.36 ...}_{01} \left( x \right) } \right) ^{-1}}{}
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  \operatorname 
                          {B}_{01} \left ( x \right ) 
l.38 ...\operatorname{B}_{01} \left( x \right) }{}
                                                   is a Bayes factor if favo...
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  unable to run pdflatex on 'Rd2.tex'
LaTeX errors:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \operatorname 
                         {P} \left ( \operatorname {H_0} | x \right ) = \lef...
l.36 ...}_{01} \left( x \right) } \right) ^{-1}}{}
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ratorname {P} \left ( \operatorname 
                                                  {H_0} | x \right ) = \left...
l.36 ...}_{01} \left( x \right) } \right) ^{-1}}{}
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \operatorname 
                         {B}_{01} \left ( x \right ) 
l.36 ...}_{01} \left( x \right) } \right) ^{-1}}{}
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  \operatorname 
                          {B}_{01} \left ( x \right ) 
l.38 ...\operatorname{B}_{01} \left( x \right) }{}
                                                   is a Bayes factor if favo...
Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
The file /var/folders/np/vk9nrhgx06zbfp3tqkrsn7km0000gn/T/RtmpKg4l2G/bfactor_to_prob.pdf does not exist.
```

`devtools::build_manual` and `R CMD build` also give these same errors. `R CMD check` succeeds and `R CMD check --as-cran gives` this note:

```
Package has help file(s) containing install/render-stage \Sexpr{} expressions but no prebuilt PDF manual.
```

As listed in the `mathjaxr` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mathjaxr/mathjaxr.pdf) I have:

- Included `mathjaxr` in the `imports` field of the DESCRIPTION file
- Included `mathjaxr` in the RdMacros field of the DESCRIPTION file
- Included `\loadmathjax` in the `@description` section of each function using `mathjaxr`
- Added `@import mathjaxr` to the NAMESPACE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering the PDF you are limited in the LaTeX control sequences. It seems that `\operatorname` is not recognized. You may either want to replace it for one that is accepted by both html and PDF or to use the `\mjteqn` and `\mjtdeqn` macros where you can specify different equations for PDF, html and ASCII.